# Confluent HDFS Sink connector error while connecting HDFS to Hive

Tags: apache-kafka, hive, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Trying to push messages from Kafka to Hive by using confluent HDFS Sink connector. Successfully moved data from Kafka to HDFS, but while connecting Hive from HDFS is failing with below error,

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf\n\tat io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.HiveMetaStore.(HiveMetaStore.java:55)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.hive.HiveMetaStore.(HiveMetaStore.java:32)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.initializeHiveServices(DataWriter.java:291)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.(DataWriter.java:218)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.(DataWriter.java:84)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.start(HdfsSinkTask.java:91)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:305)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:184)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:234)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n",

The same server I can connect Hive from HDFS manually through beeline connect